# How to use windows application installed on server from remote computers?

Tags: c#, sql

I have an C#.Net windows application developed and has installed it on server (which is nothing but my pc) now I want to allow remote computers to use that application, but I am getting error as this particular remote computer Login to this user "abc" is failed.

I searched for solutions and have tried giving permissions to the public users in SQL server database and have done all the methods which is mentioned in this following link, step by step procedure. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

then too I am not able to find solution for this. Please help me solving this. I would appreciate if someone suggests me step by step procedure.

As I am very new to the development, this is my first job and I am all alone to develop this application since I am the only software developer in our company.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with the users logging in using remote desktop? Or are they installing the application on their machines and you are having trouble accessing the SQL server instance on your machine?

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur reply and yes, its with users logging from remote desktop but currently application does not have any different login, if once this stage is cleared, I will make the login for different users with different access rights and the application is installed only on server and I  use .exe file of the application from the server to run the application. Application loads properly and run but when it comes to the connection with database, it throws an error like Login failed for User 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean to share a windows desktop application over your network with others, or a web application to share with others.
For the first one (windows desktop), y'll have to make a installation of the application. (Menu Build => publish {project name }

For the other option you need a web-server. Mostly available by a provider, but also to create for internal use, (server 2012).

Beside that, there a small solution that will create a similar environment.

Lets flow the information to help you to get along

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for ur reply. Yes it is to share windows application over the network. I have tried publishing the project and trying to use it from remote desktop, but it was giving some authentication error, the application never used to load. So now I use the .exe file of the application from remote desktop by placing the shortcut of the .exe file in a sharing folder in server and access that from remote desktop. Now the application run and loads perfectly but when it needs to connect to the database, it throws an error of Login failed for user 'abc'.

Answer (score 0):

For the desktop. You've choose by publish "cd or dvd"or "from a unc path or file share"  option to set it up for installation? other wise that's the case.

If you authenticate with the database, i'll understand the authentication error.

That's the last part. 
I think your database(DB) has a local connection which works only on your machine.
Your DB got to have a access(connection) where all application can reach it.
I'll can't remember it for msSQL (Ask google), mySQL takes care of it by ip of the machine where you have the DB engine running and (standard) port 3306.
If you'll tell the application in his connectionstring (app.config) this information it will connect from all places (even your local machine) with that connection and will work on all computers who can reach the DB.

Hope it helps you futher

Comment: For publishing i have chosen unc path or file share option to set it up for installation. But when i try running the setup file from published folder at remote desktop, it gives an error as cannot retrieve application, authentication error. What shall i do for this ? And now that database accessing error is cleared, i just re-installed the SQL server and did the changes again. It is working perfectly using .exe file of the application. But now I want to use the application by publishing it. Help me doing that please.